# how to find the difference between two rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like below i need to find the difference between two tables values and their column names is it possible in mysql ?

Table looks like this

***Table1***

```
id | ArtNo     | Barcode       | CArtNo | Description | SizeDesc 

1  | O15040034 | 5704039086589 | 1235748 | Desc       | 40X50cm
```

***Table2***

```
id | ArtNo     | Barcode       | CArtNo  | Description | SizeDesc 

1  | O15040034 | 5704045086589 | 8759s89 | Desc        | 40X50cm
```

***My Code***

Like as usual i'll write the sql code and fetch the column and condition is there any easy way in mysql query to my expected result ?

```
$sql = "select * from Table1 where ArtNo = 'O15040034'";
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if($artno != $artno){
   //some condition here
}
```

Apart from these any queries to reach my target ?

Comment: no i have another primary key i just put it for example

Comment: please update with the primary key name

Comment: you can check it now

Comment: what is the type of CArtNo ?

Comment: something **different**, but I just want to suggest you would stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and will be removed from PHP 7, start using **PDO** or **mysqli_*** functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the rows from both tables that any of their column doesn't match (apart from `id`) using this:

```
SELECT aa.id AS aa_id, aa.artNo AS aa_art_no, aa.Barcode AS aa_barcode, aa.CArtNo AS aa_cart_no, 
        aa.Description AS aa_description, aa.SizeDesc AS aa_size_desc,
        bb.artNo AS bb_art_no, bb.Barcode AS bb_barcode, bb.CArtNo AS bb_cart_no, 
        bb.Description AS bb_description, bb.SizeDesc AS bb_size_desc
FROM Table1 AS aa, Table2 AS bb
WHERE aa.id = bb.id AND (
    aa.artNo != bb.artNo OR aa.Barcode != bb.Barcode OR aa.CArtNo != bb.CArtNo 
    OR aa.Description != bb.Description OR aa.SizeDesc != bb.SizeDesc
)
```

Also, as @Naruto said don't use `mysql_*` functions because they are deprecated.

Comment: may need to alias the fields so they can be referenced from php as Barcode distinct from Barcode